# System.getenv("computername") truncating return value

Tags: java, windows, hostname, getenv, computer-name

What is the difference between `System.getenv("computername")` and `System.getenv("hostname")` in Java?

Is there any character limit on the computer name when retrieving it using the `getenv()` method?

I have a lengthy hostname and `System.getenv("computername")` seems to be truncating it to 15 characters. OS used is Windows.

Comment: Is this specific to Java?  What happens when you view the environment variable in `cmd`?

Comment: this is specific to java when the value is retrieved using java code. it is fine from the cmd prompt.

Comment: Are you suggesting that `getenv("hostname")` doesn't truncate the return value? Do you get back more than 15 characters with that environment variable?

Comment: No. Wrote a few lines of code and found that computername is for Windows env and hostname is for unix env. Still unsure about the 15 character limit.

Answer (score 1):

The truncation in Windows is due to NetBIOS having a computer name length limit of 15 characters.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909264

Answer (score 1):

This is working:

```
try {
return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
return "Error: UnknownHostException";
}
```

Hope I help you.

Sam'

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple test application:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(System.getenv("computername"));
  }
}
```

and then executed:

```
set COMPUTERNAME=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
java Test
```

which printed:

`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

Works fine in both Java 5 and 7 on Windows. No sign of truncation.

Comment: Based on your code here, I tried setting the computername and executing the program. It works fine. I get the expected computername. But when I try to get the computername of my machine on a network I get the truncated value.

Comment: And `echo %COMPUTERNAME%` on the command line shows the untruncated value?

Comment: No, it shows the proper value. Executing the program from cmd prompt after doing a SET also shows proper value. Only when the actual computername is long (not via SET), I see the truncated value when I execute the program from eclipse.